# CSS shine effect-timed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a button that can be activated or deactivated. When it's activated, I want a shine effect to occur every five seconds or so. I've been looking at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AntonTrollback/nqQc7/

and have attempted to redesign it so that the div around my button will be toggled with the class "icon-effect", creating the shine effect, and then toggled off after about a second, and then it'll do that every five seconds. I edited the fiddle to create the div

```
<div id = 'my_button_div>
<div>
```

and gave various properties to make a red box, essentially. Then, I left the icon effect class as the fidde has it, and ran a time function

```
setInterval(function () {
                $('#my_ button_div').toggleClass('icon-effect');
                setTimeout(function () {
                     $('#my_ button_div').toggleClass('icon-effect');
                }, 1000);
            }, 5000);
```

this is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/286/

but I can't seem to get it to work. I left the hover stuff there, but it should just trigger a shine effect at those allotted times.

Comment: You have a space in between #my and _button_div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's several issues with the jsFiddle you posted:

1. It's not importing jQuery, which means `$` won't be defined
2. You're toggling the `icon-effect` class on the actual element, but it should be on a sub-element
3. There's a space in the id of the actual element when referenced in JavaScript
4. The `.icon-effect` sub-element is defined separately from the `#my_button_div` element (it needs to be inside it)

Here's a fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/289/

Comment: Is it possible to get this effect with one class? In these examples there's the icon-effect class and then the shine class. What if one has a button inside of the div. And the button has its own styling, etc. Is it possible to toggle ONE class onto and off of the button that will give the shine effect?

Answer (score 0):

You have some coding errors that you need to address first:

**Change this:**

```
<div id = 'my_button_div>
<div>
```

**To this:**

```
<div id="my_button_div"></div>
```

---

**Change this:**

```
$('#my_ button_div').toggleClass('…');
```

**To this:**

```
$('#my_button_div').toggleClass('…');
```

---

Now, to seamlessly use the styles from the [Gallagher/Coyier example](http://jsfiddle.net/AntonTrollback/nqQc7/), you need to add `class="icon"` to `<div id="my_button_div">` and nest `<span class="icon-effect"></span>` inside of it.

**Like so:**

```
<div class="icon" id="my_button_div">
    <span class="icon-effect"></span>
</div>
```

Then, instead of using the `:hover` pseudo-class, you'll apply some special "triggered" class instead via jQuery.

**So, this:**

```
.icon:hover .icon-effect {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
}
```

**becomes this:**

```
.icon.triggered .icon-effect {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
}
```

**And this:**

```
$('#my_ button_div').toggleClass('icon-effect');
```

**Becomes this:**

```
$('#my_ button_div').toggleClass('triggered');
```

```js
setInterval(function () {
    $('#my_button_div').toggleClass('triggered');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#my_button_div').toggleClass('triggered');
    }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

```css
/* Icon */

.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
    
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* "shine" element */
/* Could be a pseudo element but they lack support for CSS transitions in some browsers */

.icon .icon-effect {
  position: absolute;
  top: -110%;
  left: -210%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;

  opacity: 0;
  
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left top, right top,
    color-stop(0%  ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
    color-stop(75% ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
    color-stop(90% ,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)),
    color-stop(100%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0))
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%,6
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 75%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );

  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg);
    
  -webkit-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
       -o-transition-property: left, top, opacity;
          transition-property: left, top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
          transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
     -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
      -ms-transition-timing-function: ease;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
}

/* Trigger effect */

.icon.triggered .icon-effect {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -30%;
  left: -30%;
}

/* Active state */

.icon:active .icon-effect {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon" id="my_button_div">
    <span class="icon-effect"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at the comment I posted above in regards to the button? I really appreciate your help